# Постоянное возвращение значения из класса в форму

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с проблемой возвращения значений из класса в форму,
Раньше это не вызывало у меня проблем, но тут немного иной случай, значения должны постоянно передаваться на все формы, если ее открыли и присваиваться Лейблу, т.к. в классе стоит таймер на обратный отсчет. У меня выходило только один раз присвоить значения, обращаясь из формы к классу

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //код
        //Обращение к классу
        Time SetTime = new Time();
    }

    //Прием значения из класса
    public TimeSpan GetTime
    {
        get
        {
            //Получение переменной
            return Time.RemainingTime;
        }

        set
        {
            //Установка значения
            lblTimer.Text = value.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Метод в котором мы возвращаем значения в форму

```
class Time
{
    static public TimeSpan RemainingTime {get; set;}
    MainForm Form = new MainForm();

    public Time()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //код
        //Возврат значения в форму
        Form.GetTime= RemainingTime;
    }
}
```

Так же выполнял трассировку, ставил точки во всех методах, которые взаимодействуют со значениями и заметил, что при обращении к `Form.GetTime= RemainingTime;` он не ссылается на `GetTime` в основной форме
Сам таймер работает и рассчитывает дату, но не возвращает значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не создавайте экземпляр `MainForm` в классе - передавайте его в конструктор.
Тот `Form`, который Вы создали при помощи `new MainForm` - это совсем не тот `MainForm`, который Вы видите на экране.

Добавьте конструктор, принимающий класс `MainForm`:

```
class Time
{
    static public TimeSpan RemainingTime {get; set;}
    MainForm Form;

    public Time(MainForm form)
    {
        Form=form;
    }

    //Таймер

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //код
        //Возврат значения в форму
        Form.GetTime= RemainingTime;
    }
}
```

Ну и в MainForm, соответственно:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //код
    //Обращение к классу
    Time SetTime = new Time(this);
}
```

Comment: Немного не то, вылетело из головы, этот класс будет потом применяться ко всем формам и возможно привязка в конструкторе к конкретной форме, не то что нужно, а так конструктор `Time` и так уже существовал, я поправил вопрос. Прошу прощения за то, что упустил такую деталь

Comment: Хотя ладно, додумаю, если не будет работать на других формах, Спасибо за решение